# How can I re-write this query so I am not excluding data without tags?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently, this query excludes records in my report that do not contain tags.  Can someone please help me change this query so it returns all records, with or without tags?

```
SELECT
  cmsdocument.internaldocid,
  cmsdocument.documentid,
  cmsdocument.versionid,
  cmsdocversion.title,
  string_agg(cmstag.tagname, ',')
FROM 
  public.cmsobjecttag,
  public.cmstag,
  public.cmsdocument,
  public.cmsdocversion,
  public.cmsuser
WHERE 
  cmsobjecttag.tagid = cmstag.tagid AND
  cmsobjecttag.objectid = cmsdocument.internaldocid AND
  cmsdocument.internaldocid = cmsdocversion.internaldocid AND
  cmsdocument.userid = cmsuser.userid AND
  cmsdocversion.state = 'published' AND
  cmsobjecttag.objecttype = '102'
GROUP BY 
  cmsdocument.internaldocid,
  cmsdocument.documentid,
  cmsdocument.versionid,
  cmsdocversion.title;
```

Comment: Have you tried removing "cmsobjecttag.tagid = cmstag.tagid AND"?

Comment: You can use `left outer join` for `public.cmstag` instead of implicit  `inner join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @notulysses commented, you should use an outer join. For example (untested):

```
SELECT
  d.internaldocid,
  d.documentid,
  d.versionid,
  dv.title,
  string_agg(t.tagname, ',')
FROM 
  public.cmsdocument d
  JOIN public.cmsdocversion dv ON d.internaldocid = dv.internaldocid AND dv.state = 'published'
  JOIN public.cmsuser u ON d.userid = u.userid
  LEFT JOIN public.cmsobjecttag ot ON d.internaldocid = ot.objectid AND ot.objecttype = '102'
  LEFT JOIN public.cmstag t ON t.tagid = ot.tagid
GROUP BY 
  d.internaldocid,
  d.documentid,
  d.versionid,
  dv.title;
```

Comment: Could you be more specific @Pavel Gatnar? Is there a syntax error or are documents without tags still being excluded?

Comment: Updated to add a `LEFT JOIN` for `public.cmstg` and added `ot.objecttype = '102'` to the join condition.

Comment: Yes, as you can see I did the same. Are there any outstanding problems with this answer?